# Direct initialization of temporary object for reference type

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

I'm curious why this program wont compile.

```
class A{};
void f(const A &a){}
int main(){
    const A &a(A())
    f(a);

    // but the following would work if
    // i deleted the above two lines of code

    //A b;
    //const A &a(b);
    //f(a);

}
```

I think the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952918/direct-initialization-and-copy-initialization-of-reference) says that there is no difference between direct initialization and copy initialization of a reference type, but when I try to compile this (I'm using MinGW) I get the error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const A&' from expression of type 'const A& (*)(A (*)())'
    f(a);
```

I'm also curious how operator precedence works with

```
const A& (*)(A (*)())
```

Comment: Google "most vexing parse".

Comment: And even if it compiled you'd take a reference to a temporary: unspecified behaviour. The code below is correct.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre const reference to temporary is completely fine

Comment: is the ref useable afterwards? The temporary will be disposed of in the next line right?